# ORA-27046: file size is not a multiple of logical block size

Tags: oracle, docker, containers

I have oracle19c container, running by docker-compose:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  oracle:
    image: container-registry.oracle.com/database/enterprise:19.3.0.0
    container_name: oracle19c
    ports:
      - 1521:1521
    volumes:
      - oracle19c:/opt/oracle/oradata
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime
    shm_size: '2gb'
networks:
  oracle19c:
    external: yes
volumes:
  oracle19c:
    external: yes
```

After some tuning, like turning on archive log, now I cannot start oracle.

```
SQL> startup;
ORA-01078: failure in processing system parameters
LRM-00109: could not open parameter file '/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/initORCLCDB.ora'
```

Then I tried to create pfile from sfile, it shows error:

```
SQL> create pfile='/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/initORCLCDB.ora' from spfile='/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/spfileORCLCDB.ora';
create pfile='/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/initORCLCDB.ora' from spfile='/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/spfileORCLCDB.ora'
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01565: error in identifying file
'/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/spfileORCLCDB.ora'
ORA-27046: file size is not a multiple of logical block size
Additional information: 1
```

This is the detail of spfile:

```
bash-4.2$ cd /opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/dbs/
bash-4.2$ ls
init.ora orapwORCLCDB  spfileORCLCDB.ora
bash-4.2$ cat spfileORCLCDB.ora
C"▒▒f▒▒CCC"["ORCLCDB.__data_transfer_cache_size=0
ORCLCDB.__db_cache_size=889192448
ORCLCDB.__inmemory_ext_roarea=0
ORCLCDB.__inmemory_ext_rwarea=0
ORCLCDB.__java_pool_size=0
ORCLCDB.__large_pool_size=67108864
ORCLCDB.__oracle_base='/opt/oracle'#ORACLE_BASE set from environment
ORCLCDB.__pga_aggregate_target=536870912
ORCLCDB.__sga_target=1610612736
ORCLCDB.__shared_io_pool_size=83886080
ORCLCDB.__shared_pool_size=520093696
ORCLCDB.__streams_pool_size=33554432
ORCLCDB.__unified_pga_pool_size=0
*.CC"v9audit_file_dest='/opt/oracle/admin/ORCLCDB/adump'
*.audit_sys_operations=false
*.audit_trail='none'
*.compatible='19.0.0'
*.control_files='/opt/oracle/oradata/ORCLCDB/control01.ctl'
*.db_block_size=8192
*.db_flashback_retention_target=1440
*.db_name='ORCLCDB'
*.diagnostic_dest='/opt/oracle'
*.dispatchers='(PROTOCOL=TCP) (SERVICE=ORCLCDBXDB)'
*.enable_pluggable_database=true
*.CC":)local_listener=''
*.log_archive_format='%s_%t_%r.ARC'
*.log_archive_start=TRUE
*.nls_language='AMERICAN'
*.nls_territory='AMERICA'
*.open_cursors=300
*.pga_aggregate_target=512m
*.processes=640
*.remote_login_passwordfile='EXCLUSIVE'
*.sga_target=1536m
*.undo_tablespace='UNDOTBS1'
CC"FeCC"EeCC"DeC
```

Please help me how to fix this. I need to keep the data which is already mounted to volume.

Thank you all.

Comment: did you edit the spfile directly with any tool that would have altered its original size as it was created by Oracle?